# Issue with expanding box script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got an issue with a script I tried to make, but I don't know what seems wrong with it. It's about expanding a div box by clicking a 'read more' button/link.

This is the script I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".hiddencontainer").hide(); 
        });
          $("#trigger").toggle(function(){
                  $(this).addClass("active");
                  }, function () {
                  $(this).removeClass("active");
          });
          $("#trigger").click(function(){
                  $(this).next(".hiddencontainer").slideToggle("slow");     
});
```

==================================================================================

This is the CSS I'm using for this:

```
.readmore{
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: right;
}

.hiddencontainer{
  color: #000000;
}
```

==================================================================================

And last but not least The HTML I'm using:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <h3>Software repair</h3>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p> 
          <p class="readmore" id="trigger"><a href="#" />Read more</a></p>
<div class="hiddencontainer">
     <p>Here goes whatever you want to expand/collapse</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Could somebody please push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your event handlers inside your DOM ready function. Also, `.toggle()` is deprecated in newer versions of jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hiddencontainer").hide(); 

    $("#trigger").toggle(function(){
         $(this).addClass("active");
    }, function () {
         $(this).removeClass("active");
    });

    $("#trigger").click(function(){
         $(this).next(".hiddencontainer").slideToggle("slow");     
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, with that my 'read more' button has disappeared. Any iedea how that happened?

Comment: Your use of the `toggle` function may have something to do with it, try removing it.

Comment: Many thanks! It was the .toggle function, I changed that to .click and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure trigger toggle and click are inside document.ready.

Comment: I'm quite new in js/jQuery, but could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: in the third line you are using   });  ..instead place it at the end of the code